# node speaker Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)

Tags: node.js, audio, node-speaker

I'm trying to use node-speaker to speak an Amazon polly stream, once read I'm saving into a file a cache and second time I want to read that file with the speaker.

It works well but the script is exiting with `Process finished with exit code 132 (interrupted by signal 4: SIGILL)`

Here is my method:

```
speak: (text, cacheDisabled = false) => {
    const hash = path.join(__dirname, 'cache', crypto.createHash('md5').update(text).digest('hex') + '.pcm')
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.exists(hash, exist => {
        if (exist) {
          const audioFile = fs.createReadStream(hash)
          audioFile.pipe(this.player)

        }
        else {
          const audioFile = fs.createWriteStream(hash)

          const params = {
            'Text': text,
            'OutputFormat': 'pcm',
            'VoiceId': this.config.voiceId
          }
          this.polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
            }
            else if (data) {
              if (data.AudioStream instanceof Buffer) {
                // Initiate the source
                const bufferStream = new Stream.PassThrough()
                // convert AudioStream into a readable stream
                bufferStream.end(data.AudioStream)
                // save to file
                if (!cacheDisabled && !this.cacheDisabled) {
                  bufferStream.pipe(audioFile)
                }
                // Pipe into Player
                bufferStream.pipe(this.player)
                resolve()
              }
              else {
                reject()
              }
            }
          })
        }
      })
    })
  }
```

And my player is basic:

```
this.player = new Speaker({
      channels: 1,
      bitDepth: 16,
      sampleRate: 16000
    })
```

Any idea how to prevent that ? Very annoying because it crash the project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by using `npm install speaker --mpg123-backend=openal` but this module doesn't seems maintain anymore :(